# Redirecting without changing the displayed URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, web, dns

tried to search a lot in StackOverflow but nothing solved my problem.

I got a domain in a server (let's call it mydomain.com) and a subdomain called for example mydomain.com/subdomain. I have configured my DNS to have a redirect, so when I write www.subdomain.com it brings me to www.mydomain.com/subdomain.

Is there a way (via DNS, CNAME, .htaccess, anything else?) to perform my redirection but having my browser still displaying www.subdomain.com in the URL bar?

Sorry for bad english

Comment: You can do this with [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass), alternatively you can do with [mod_rewrite P flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) but for performance reasons proxypass is recommended.

Comment: There is an error in your question. in a URL such as subdomain.example.com/subdirectory/ , the subdomain is “subdomain” and the subdirectory is “subdirectory” (also sometimes called a folder). If you are still unclear see this https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-glossary-url-definitions/
Took it from https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/subdomains-and-subdirectories/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following code in root `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomain/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain/$1 [L,NE]
```

**Update :** as per  javidazac comment  , i should explain that to questioner , that he means sub directory not subdomain , but i will consider that you have sub directory called subdomain

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However It didn't work. It seems that actually it's doing nothing at all!I really don't know where am I mistaking...